# Is there a way to check Ubuntu installation health?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, system

I'm a person who wants to be sure before continue working on his system. Because of that, I would like to know if my Ubuntu installation is in a good condition or not. Some of the things I would like to know:

- If there is a missing necessary package or not.
- All packages are healthy.
- There is no missing file in system.
- There is no broken package
- and etc...

Long story short is there a way I can check if my installation is healthy, in a good condition or not.

If that's important, I'm using 14.04 at the moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

you will be warned about problems if there are any related to packages. That solves these 2:

- All packages are healthy.
- There is no broken package

That command will install all updates for your installed software. I assume "healthy" means as up to date as possible. If there are broken packages you will get warned about them as soon as those are checked.

Regarding ...

- If there is a missing necessary package or not.
- There is no missing file in system.

How would a system be able to tell you if a file is missing? In general a program will throw some sort of error when it needs it during execution of that software. Something like  "segmentation fault" or a python error. If there are none you should assume all if fine.

If you would want a list of all the files missing you would need to start every application on your system. Undoable even automated.

Comment: This won't work on a machine without internet access